# PHP foreach loop using a MySQL ID

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

Is it possible to use a `foreach` loop for a specific ID in MySQL?

This is what I'm trying to work to (specifically the part: `foreach ($row["cid"]` )

```
foreach ($row["cid"] as $value) {

if ($row["v"] == 'x')
{
    echo $row["n"];     
    break;                  
}
```

Comment: what does not work in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach()` requires an array as the first parameter. In your example, `$row["c_id"]` is not an array, so the statement fails.

Instead, you can use a `while` loop to process each returned row:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) {
    if ( $row['value'] == 'Yes' ) {
        echo $row['c_name'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: fantastic idea, thank you so much for your help George. I shall try that out.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { $value = $row['cid']; ... }
```

But can't understand why do you need that $value if you don't use it.